# NullPointerException on loading data into Grakn

Tags: backup, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have created a backup of Grakn with the exporter tool like this:

```
./grakn server export 'old_test' backup.grakn
$x isa export,
    has status "completed",
    has progress (100.0%),
    has count (105 / 105);
```

I then wanted to import this into a new keyspace with
`./grakn server import 'new_test' backup.grakn`

But I got this error below:

```
An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What is the version of Grakn that you are running?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your schema into the new keyspace first, this error occurs because the server cannot find a schema label in your dataset. The steps for migrating schema are described in the docs: https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/management/migration-and-backup